# How to create tags on enter press in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using a package named [textfield_tags](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_tags) which is working fine, but the tags are created on string values, but I want to create tags when user presses enter. And when the tag is created it should be added to a list named `_skillsLists`. What should I do?

**This is my code**

```dart
TextFieldTags(
  textfieldTagsController: controller,
  initialTags: _skillsLists,
  textSeparators: [''],
  letterCase: LetterCase.normal,
  validator: (String tag) {
    if (tag.length < 3) {
      return 'Tag cannot be smaller than 3 characters';
    } else if (controller.getTags!.contains(tag)) {
      return 'Tag already exists';
    }
    return null;
  },
  inputfieldBuilder: (context, tec, fn, error,
    onChanged, onSubmitted) {
      return ((context, sc, tags, onTagDelete) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: TextField(
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   print('The value entered is : $value');
              // },
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _skillsLists.add(value);
                  });
                },
                controller: tec,
                autofocus: true,
                focusNode: fn,
                hintText: controller.hasTags
                  ? ''
                  : 'Press enter to create tags',
                errorText: error,
                prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: _distanceToField! * 0.74),
                },
              ),
```